# Centering force offsets force diagram d3js v4

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple force diagram that looks like this:

[image]

In the picture we can see nodes nicely aligned along side the x axis with a small 100px buffer zone to the left and the right of the middle (black) node. This is handled by 2 scales:

1. Left scale with range (10, width/2 - 100). 10 gives a small padding from the edge.
2. Right scale with range (width/2 + 100, width -10).

The position of the node in the middle is (width/2, height/2). The x position of red and green nodes is handled by the right/left scale as well as the axis at the bottom.

The above works fine until I add

```
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

to my force definition and the result is:

[image]

It offsets the picture to the left by x amount. Why is that?

The svg element that the nodes are appended to doesnt have any css styling (padding or margins), maybe it should? What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

[Here is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ms3ek70/1/) with the same problem. You can see that the right and left nodes are slightly off the number it should be on top of. If you would comment out **line 40** the offset is no longer.
Whilst putting this together I realised that the problem might be how my diagram's svg is constructed. At the moment its

```
svg
 |
 - g.nodes
 - g.links
 - g.axisleft
 - g.axisright
```

Nodes are appended into g.nodes element.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the code?

Comment: `forceCenter` makes the center of gravity of all the nodes equal to the given position, better to use `forceX` and `forceY`

Comment: @jrook working on fiddle, will post it once done.

Comment: @rioV8 using forceX to place the nodes into x position in the above example. Im not sure how your comment explains why the nodes are shifted tho.

Comment: why do you add a `forceCenter`? what do you want to change in the chart you already have?

Comment: @rioV8 well I have no intention on specifying force-y scale and having forceCentre helps to keep the diagram in the viewport as well as pull everything together

Comment: @jrook I updated the question with a fiddle example. Thanks

Comment: Did my answer help? Were you able to come up with a solution for this problem?

Comment: @jrook unfortunately bud, clustering is not an option but Im working on no force solution where one just specifies X and Y coordinates. Trying to find a good property for Y sorting tho. That said I havent investigated it 100%, but defenitely hould have an answer by the end of next week. If any of your suggestions will help will defenitely give points.

Answer (score 0):

It is the center of gravity of the nodes

The chart center X is 400.

The node positions are

- x1=168.68
- x2=388.68
- x3=642.68

Difference to 400

- x1= -231.32
- x2= -11.32
- x3= 242.68

If you add them up it is very close to 0.

Comment: @NeilVarnas what is changed between v2 and v1 of the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Force layout does not necessarily guarantee that the node will end up in a given starting coordinate. You are applying multiple forces to nodes and the nodes' final position is basically the result of superimposing all these forces.

In your case, the final positions are the result of interaction between `forceCenter` and `force.X`. You can remove one of them and see how the other one alone works.

One way to fix the problem in your case is to use the symmetrical nature of `forceCenter`:

```
.force('x', d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
    if (d.cl === 0)
        return width / 2;
    if (d.cl < 0)
        return xScale_lo(-5);
     return xScale_hi(5); //instead of 6
```

I am not sure how this will work when the number of nodes increases. If the goal is to have separated clusters of nodes, you can experiment with [cluster forces](https://gist.github.com/ericsoco/4e1b7b628771ae77753842e6dabfcef3).

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I do need two scales, the reason is that I need a nice buffer zone around the center node (described in question).

Comment: @NeilVarnas, You can have two scales. The point is not to try to apply margins with scales. You can also experiment with other scales other than linear to see if it helps.

Comment: If you want the left and right side to be clearly separated, I suggest you try force clustering. Here is an exmaple: https://bl.ocks.org/ericsoco/cd0c38a20141e997e926592264067db3 .

Comment: thanks for that. But there are no margins on the scales. They ( 2x scales) get the same coordinates as the points (fiddle with line 40 commented out). Once the center force is applied (w line 40) the nodes get shifted to the left by the looks of it and don’t match the x scales anymore. I don’t want to change my layout, but would love to understand/know why centre gravity shifts the nodes.  Using clustering isn’t an option but I’ll check that again.

Comment: @NeilVarnas *there are no margins on the scales*. Actually, there are: `.range([10, width / 2 - 50])`. You are trying to create some margin by changing the range. I believe that is why your center is *off*.

Comment: @NeilVarnas, you might be able to pull this off by using scales. But I wonder what the point would be. Scales are meant to facilitate data conversion between domains. The way you are using them adds unnecessary complexity to the visualization. Clustering, on the other hand, cleanly arranges a group of nodes around the desired center.

Comment: you’re absolutely right, will try removing those margins in the fiddle and let you know. Although I highly doubt it, but will try. I Believe the scales are also used for x and y axis generation quite widely as well as other conversions, like colour. I need both elements (node x position and axis) to follow the same scale because it’s variant and after certain data updates yielded by user interaction those scales will dynamically change. My main concern re complexity and efficiency  is the best html structure for all different schools elements but that’s another question another time.

Comment: as suspected, removing the margins (as well as the buffer zone) hasnt solved the problem [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ms3ek70/4/)

Comment: @NeilVarnas, I rewrote the response. See the edit. I suspect you might have some form of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe update your question with the final goal and what you ultimately want to achieve.